# Facebook ServiceConnect problem

Tags: social-media

In 11.3

`facebook = ServiceConnect["Facebook", "New"]`

takes me to a browser page with the error message:

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "HNiCrSuDMXL"
   }
}`

Can anyone else confirm this behavior? I am using Windows 7 and Google Chrome.

Comment: Hm. The error message says: "CloudConnect::fbdn: Unable to authorize request.  Please contact technical support for assistance." Maybe that's what you should do... (version 11.3 on macos).

Comment: Interesting. I don't get that error message; only the one in the browser.

Comment: I get the same thing, reported it as a bug.